# Does popup exist? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, browser, popup

I'm trying to determine whether a popup exists in javascript. I do know its name (passed in `window.open()`), but I do not have a window reference. For example consider this: I have a web page A which calls `window.open('url', 'popup')` and I have web page B which also wants to call `window.open('url', 'popup')` unless such popup exists. In this case B just focuses on popup. So web page B has no reference to popup (and it cannot have, we may assume that A and B are independent). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can, as each window is separate.  Browsers deliberately prevent on window from discovering what happens to another window.

Comment: Might want to consider rearchitecting around something like jQuery's dialogs - assuming Javascript being required isn't an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it if you play around with your window structure.

Whenever I've come across this problem I've had a main window which always exists. Then, when calling window.open, I grab the handler that that function returns and then assign it to the main window that I know will always exist.

Then, whenever calling window.open, I go off and check main window to see if it has an open window handler for the popup window.

So, assuming you have that main window that always exists (you could always use have a window that uses a frame to display your actual content so, to your users, it'll look the same), you could do something like:

```
var mainWindow = window;

while(mainWindow != mainWindow.parent){
   mainWindow = mainWindow.parent; 
}

if(mainWindow.PopupWindow === undefined || mainWindow.PopupWindow.closed){ 
  var handler = window.open('url', 'popup');
  mainWindow.PopupWindow = handler;
}
```

I've always had a few problems using the closed property of the window object, so you may need to map a function to the onunload event within the popup window that just clears out the PopupWindow variable on the mainWindow, and then add that check within your if statement too.